# Can Linq-to-SQL Do an Insert or update as needed?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5

I have a distributed app that sends data via WCF to a server to be stored in the database (SQL Server 2008).

Usually this data is new.  So I just do InsertAllOnSubmit().

But occasionally, due to communication oddities with the handheld devices that run the client side I get an object that is already in the server.

Is there a way to say InsertOrUpdateAllOnSubmit?  Or am I going to have to change my code to go through each object and check to see if it is in the database and then do and insert or update as needed?  I have quite a few object types, so that will get tedious really fast :(

Comment: How are you defining "duplicate"?  The same primary key?  Are you using identity columns for PKs?

Comment: @AaronLS - duplicate is having the same primary key (though I do get the occasional Unique constraint violation as well).  Since my data comes from lots of devices, the PKs are usually GUIDs.

Comment: So you probably don't want a InsertOrUpdate, as you wouldn't want to do an update on an existing record if there is a GUID collision?  I.e. I'm guessing two devices attempt to insert totally different data but they happened to generate the same GUID, so rather than do an update for the second record you'd want to regenerate it's GUID and then insert so that both records are added to the database with unique PK's.  Maybe your scenario is different than what I imagine but that is what I am thinking.

Comment: @AaronLS - the scenario we have is that the device sends up the data and then (for some reason we are not sure) does not get the acknowledgment that the server got the data.  We decided that the connection for these devices makes it more work than it is worth to be 100% sure that the device cleared the data before inserting it.  Besides, we want the data, even if the device is not sure it sent it.  But, either way, if the device is not 100% sure that the server got the data, it will send it again before clearing it.  So, this is not an issue of conflicting GUIDs (which would be very unlikely).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the store procedure on the database to handle Insert of duplicates.

Comment: I don't have stored procedures backing this data.  It just uses the Linq-to-SQL to do the data inserts.

Comment: You can attach a store procedure to do your inserts/updates in Linq-To-SQL.  You could write a single procedure to do both insert and update.  This might be more effecient way to handle duplicates rather than in C#.

Comment: Also note if you do this through a stored procedure you can use the new MERGE syntax to perform the insert and update in one go.  I think that was added in MS SQL 2008

Answer (score 2):

Usually what I've seen as the pattern for the scenario when you attempt to do any kind of insert or update and there is conflict, such as objects already existing, then once you detect a conflict you request the new data and apply your updates to it.  This allows you the flexibility of deciding which change wins, or prompting the user in some way letting them view the new data and decide if their data should win.  It all depends on the context and business rules.

This mostly applies to updates but maybe if you think about why these conflicts are occurring for inserts you might be able to adapt your implementation to use concurrency detection and resolution techniques.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399373.aspx